# Question marks in citation? What is the solution besides compiling 4 times?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

The problem of question mark in citation can be solved by compiling using Latex+Bibtex+Latex+Latex locally. However, it doesn't help when I submit the .tex file to a online editorial system of a journal. The conversion engine of the system can only do a single-time compiling so that the question marks are always there. The system only allows to upload .tex file, not supporting other types. Does anyone know any solution to this? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you try to include the generated `.bbl` file in your submission?

Comment: Paste the contents of the `.bbl` file in the place of `\bibliography{references.bib}`.

Comment: @marmot Thank you! The system allows only .tex file.

Comment: @HenriMenke I tried, this is a possible solution I believe. But I also use an custom .sty file which makes the conversion fails... Is there any way to also include the .sty file?

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, similar. Can I somehow include .sty file?

Comment: Where you have `\usepackage{<.sty file>}`, comment that out and immediately after it add `\makeatletter`, insert the contents of the `.sty` file, and follow that with `\makeatother`.  It might be necessary to comment out a few lines, such as `\providespackage`.  At least that's worth a try (it works best if the package isn't too large).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you so much. I will try this to see if it works!

Comment: The journal editors will probably not be very happy with the package file to begin with.

Comment: @Zahlen -- What Johannes B says about packages and journal editors is often true.  However, as I said, inserting the contents of the `.sty` file in your preamble is worth a try.  But that wasn't the topic of the original question, and that has been closed now, so if you need more help about the `.sty` file, please ask a new question.